# Composition Series in a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

In finite group we usually construct a composition series by a sequence of maximal normal subgroups. Can we construct a composition series in a finite group by a sequence of maximal normal subgroups ? Let G be a finite group. If G is simple. Then we are done. If G is not simple then we get a minimal normal subgroup of G. Now we take the quotient group  and the quotient group is simple then we are done. If the quotient is not simple then we get a minimal normal subgroup of that and repeat the same process. At some point it will stop since G is finite. Now the question is : will this produce a composition series or not  ? If not, Why ?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Minimal normal subgroups of finite groups are well-understood: they have to be a direct power of a simple group. So if a minimal normal subgroup is also maximal normal, then the group is an extension of the shape $X^k.Y$, where both $X$ and $Y$ are simple. Now, there are more restrictions. If $X$ is abelian, then $Y$ acts on $X^k$, and it must act irreducibly. If $X$ is non-abelian, then the $k$ factors are being permuted, and they must be permuted transitively. With these conditions, this becomes a characterisation.

Answer (score 3):

"Now if H is a minimal normal subgroup of G then the quotient G/H is also simple." is wrong. Example: $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$.

$C_2$ is a minimal normal and the quotient is $C_2\times C_2$, not simple.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that you misunderstood my question or i could not make you understand. My question was specifically for the composition series not for the whole group in general. Let G and K be successive terms in a composition series then K is maximal normal in G ( K not necessarily to be a maximal normal for the actual group in which the composition series is formed).

Comment: Your question contains $K, H$. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.It should be G and K. Actually i wanted to mean that we can construct composition series in a finite group by a sequence of maximal normal subgroups. Can we construct a composition series in a finite group by a sequence of minimal normal subgroups ?